# Texture a heightmap with a DisplayList & GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, terrain

```
glNewList(heightmapDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);

    // Iterate over the 'strips' of heightmap data.
    for (int z = 0; z < data.length - 1; z++) {
        // Render a triangle strip for each 'strip'.
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for (int x = 0; x < data[z].length; x++) {
            // Take a vertex from the current strip
            if (((blue[z][x] / 255) < 0.4))
                glColor4f((red[z][x] / 255) / 2
                        + (float) (Math.random() / 10), (green[z][x] / 255)
                        / 2 + (float) (Math.random() / 10),
                        (blue[z][x] / 255) / 2
                                + (float) (Math.random() / 10), 1);
            else {
                glColor4f((red[z][x] / 255) / 2
                        + (float) (Math.random() / 10), (green[z][x] / 255)
                        / 2 + (float) (Math.random() / 10),
                        (blue[z][x] / 255) / 2
                                + (float) (Math.random() / 10), 1);
            }
            if (data[z][x] >= WATER_LEVEL -10){

            glVertex3f(x, data[z][x], z);

            // Take a vertex from the next strip
            glVertex3f(x, data[z + 1][x], z + 1);

            }

        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glEndList();
```

I would like to add a texture to the above code.

Preferrably, I would like to make the texture to vary depending on the height of the terrain. That way, I would be able to create a nice-looking terrain which is not 100% the same.

As you can see, I am using a DisplayList and a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, which I am calling by using `glCallList(heightmapDisplayList)'.

Currently I just set a colour depending on the height, however this does not look excellent since I `glScalef(8, 1, 8)` the map up so that I can get a large map with fewer vertices.

So how can I do this without just setting the colour per vertex or something similar?

Comment: Have you read about vertex and pixel shaders?

Comment: Your question is really too broad for the SO format. You should be able to find tutorials on texture mapping online. You will need to generate texture ids (`glGenTextures`), bind them, load texture data (`glTexImage2D`), and define texture coordinates (`glTexCoord`) instead of colors.

Comment: Also, even though that's not part of your question, you may want to consider modern OpenGL features. Display lists are very obsolete, and deprecated. Look up VBOs (vertex buffer object), etc.

Comment: I don't see how any of the above comments help me.
Vertex and pixel shaders do not help me add a TEXTURE.
How is the texture too broad? How is it more broad than say, "How can I delete content on a JFrame", something I asked a few days ago.
I use VBOs for plenty of stuff, however never got around to implementing them for the heightmap... And still doesn't solve my issue.